# Convertion of json to list in c#

Tags: json, list

i have a json string like below

```
{"Page Load":{"Entity":[{"NamesList":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Food"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Power"},{"Id":3,"Name":"air"},
{"Id":4,"Name":"water"},{"Id":5,"Name":"nature"},{"Id":6,"Name":"another"}],
"Transaction information":{"success":true,"return val":"","return datatype":"","error":""},
"Metadata":{"Type":"Abstract"}}],"next records":false},"Processing Time":14}
```

i want to get the values of NamesList(returning from json) to my Root class.

[Myclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RZH7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
```

**T** is your root class.